# How to Find specific digit length, and delte / filter out the rest with Noted++?

Tags: notepad++, filtering, delete-row

I've searched online to see if someone else has already asked for this possible solution. The closest that I've been able to find was this. Under find, replace tab, FindWhat:^(\d+).*$
Replace with:$1

I will be working with documents that have more than 10 columns. I need to copy and paste the text from a PDF file into a plain text document and filter out everything except the 11 digit code present in column number nine.

I believe the solution I posted above would include numbers from other columns. I'm assuming there's a way to restrict the solution I posted to only apply to an 11 digit value rather than any digit found in the text file.

Below is my example.

Column # 1  *11*
Column # 2  *1*
Column # 3  *1*
Column # 4  *1*
Column # 5  *Unit*
Column # 6  *123456*
Column # 7  *123456*
Column # 8  *front*
Column # 9 **12345678911**

I would like to be able to have notepad plus plus delete everything except any 11 digit code present in column number nine.

Comment: What do you mean by "column number nine"? What is a "column" in your file and how are columns separated? Please [edit] the question to provide an example with three or four lines of text copied from your input file. You can replace characters with 'X' or something if you need to hide names etc, but preserve the actual layout. Show the desired output for these example lines.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Please note - this is a solution for 9 columns only! As mentioned by others please add more details about the format of your text file.

---

Assuming you have the following columns:

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 Column 4 Column 5 Column 6 Column 7 Column 8 Column 9 
11       1        1        1        Unit-x   123456   123456   front    12345678911
12       3        4        5        Unit-y   123456   123456   front    12345678911
```

or something like this

```
Column 1;Column 2;Column 3;Column 4;Column 5;Column 6;Column 7;Column 8;Column 9
11;1;1;1;Unit-x;123456;123456;front;12345678911
12;3;4;5;Unit-y;123456;123456;front;12345678911
```

or some more in a text file line by line you'd go through following steps:

- Open your file
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(.+)([0-9]{11}$)`
- Replace with: `\2`
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd>
- Clean the header for your needs.